# How to parse JSON with javascript from url with authentication

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, authentication

Im trying to parse some JSON from a URL. It is password protected and I cannot figure it out. Tried many tutorials and many blogs but nothing worked so far.

Ive got set up this basic code, just to see if it returns anything. Parsing will be easier. But it seems im not even getting data from the url.

I just need it to send me something back and display it in html.

```
<pre>
var base_url = "https://backend.sigfox.com/api/devices/166A4/messages";

function example()
{
    var response = "";
    var form_data = {
        username: "57616e7551e24e4c99acf6f3",
        password: "fd7e78536e4e834e9ce4fba0bf747947"
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: base_url, 
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert(response);

        var json_obj = $.parseJSON(response);//parse JSON

            var output="<ul>";
            for (var i in json_obj) 
            {
                output+="<li>" + json_obj[i].data+ "</li>";
            }
            output+="</ul>";

            $('span').html(output);
        },
        dataType: "json"//set to JSON    
    })    
}
</pre>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: fix the syntax errors in the code please.

Answer (score 0):

Test your code every step of the way to make sure it's doing what you want.  First, make sure your password is working.  Once you've tested that, then print out the raw JSON data and copy and paste it into a parser like

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ or http://jsonformatter.org/

make sure the JSON is valid

After you have tested everything, Then feed it into the methods you are using to parse the JSON.